# Cual corrección necesita esta linea de código py

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.7

[image: tengo error y me sale esto 1]

Este es el código

```py
T = 1 #Se normaliza respecto de la frecuencia de muestreo 
Wo = 1 / float(2 * T) #Frecuencia de Nyquist 
taps = 65 #Numero de coeficientes del filtro 
K = taps / 2 
step = 1 / float(K * T) 
f = np.arange(-1 , 1 , step) 
alfa = 0.5 #Factor de despliegue 
W = alfa * Wo + Wo 
H = sample_sqrtHrc(f, W, Wo) 
hc = np.fft.ifft(H) 
h = np.real(hc) 
L=len(h) 

#  esta linea de codigo es el causante necesito ayuda, que modifico
b = np.concatenate((h[L-K:L], h[0:K]), axis=None)
```

Comment: Evidentemente L, K o ambos tienen un valor que no se puede usar en slices, presumiblemente un flotante (ya que en una parte los restas). Sin saber que contienen exactamente esas variables no puedo ayudar mucho más. Que contienen?

Comment: T = 1 #Se normaliza respecto de la frecuencia de muestreo
    Wo = 1 / float(2 * T) #Frecuencia de Nyquist
    taps = 65 #Numero de coeficientes del filtro
    K = taps / 2
    step = 1 / float(K * T)
    f = np.arange(-1 , 1 , step)
    alfa = 0.5 #Factor de despliegue
    W = alfa * Wo + Wo
    H = sample_sqrtHrc(f, W, Wo)
    hc = np.fft.ifft(H)
    h = np.real(hc)
    L=len(h)

Comment: contiene eso bro

Comment: Gracias! Aquí es donde está el flotante: K = taps / 2. L no es flotante por que la función len SIEMPRE devuelve un entero. 65/2 es 32.5. Si quieres usar este numero en un slice, tendrás que convertirlo en entero. Puedes redondearlo (función round), redondearlo hacia abajo (función int) o hacia arriba (math.ceil).

Comment: gracias men !!!!!!!

Comment: Por cierto, en Python NO es lo mismo 10 y 10.0 en lo que a tipo de dato corresponde (uno es entero y otro flotante).

Comment: De nada Apol!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
K = taps // 2
k = int(np.floor((len(x) // M) * M))
    x = x[0:k]
    x = x.reshape((len(x) // M, M))
```

Comment: y esto que hace? por qué soluciona tu problema?